# Initialising modelformset_factory without queryset

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to use a `modelformset_factory` for a bunch of models which have been processed/filtered after they have been retrieved from db. It basically means that the models are already available the way I want them for the `modelformset_factory`. I was wondering if there is a way to pass the factory a list of models (without hitting the db via the `queryset` argument)?

One way I can think of is to mock a QuerySet to return the processed list of models and use this as the [queryset argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset).

Another way might be to transform the models into a list of dicts using `model_to_dict` and using a the `initial` argument (since modelformset_factory is a subclass of formset_factory) - not quite sure if `modelformset_factory` would allow me to do that...

I would then have to cache the models I used to create the forms inbetween requests so that I can skip the retrieval/processing of the models when the actual POST  data arrives.

Does anyone know if there is any better way of solving this kind of problem?

Note: I would like to use a `modelformset_factory` since I would like to take advantage of the formset's automatic prefixing and handling of the forms.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never...

I ran into this problem too.  I managed it by passing model_to_dict as the initial parameter.  Beware, though, model_to_dict doesn't return ForeignKey or ManyToMany fields, so I had to pass those parameters in explicitly (Assume MyModelClass has a ForeignKey to MyRelatedClass):

A helper fn in forms.py:

```
def MyInlineFormSetFactory(*args,**kwargs):
  _prefix     = kwargs.pop("prefix","formset")
  _request    = kwargs.pop("request",None)
  _initial    = kwargs.pop("initial",[])
  _instance   = kwargs.pop("instance")
  new_kwargs = {
      "can_delete" : False,
      "extra"      : kwargs.pop("extra",0),
      "form"       : MyForm,
      "fk_name"    : "my_related_name"
  }
  new_kwargs.update(kwargs)
  _formset = inlineformset_factory(MyRelatedModelClass,MyModelClass,*args,**new_kwargs)
  if _request and _request.method == "POST":
    # initialize w/ the request in the event of POST
    return _formset(_request.POST,instance=_instance,prefix=_prefix)
  # otherwise initialize w/ the initial kwarg
  return _formset(initial=_initial,instance=_instance,prefix=_prefix)
```

A helper fn someplace else:

```
def get_initial_data(model,update_fields={}):
  dict = model_to_dict(model)
  # here is where I add the fields that model_to_dict ignores
  dict.update(update_fields)
  return dict
```

And in my view...

```
my_related_model = MyRelatedModelClass.objects.get(pk=42)
my_models = MyModelClass.objects.filter(some_key="some_value")
my_initial_data = [get_initial_data(my_model,{"my_related_name" : my_related_model}) for my_model in my_models]
my_formset = MyInlineFormSetFactory(instance=my_related_model,request=request,initial=my_initial_data,extra=len(my_initial_data))
```

I'm using inline formset factories, but you get the idea.